# SQL Linking Values From Different Tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I have the following tables

```
[Items] [I]
[ID] [Date] [Item] [Qty]
1    06/11  Bat    2
2    06/11  Ball   2
3    07/11  Bat    3
4    07/11  Ball   2
5    07/11  Pump   1

[Goods1] [G1]
[ID] [Item] [Date] [Price]
1    Bat    06/11   20.00
2    Bat    07/11   21.00

[Goods2] [G2]
[ID] [Date] [Price]
1    06/11   12.50
2    07/11   12.55
```

I want to join them up, and take the prices from each day, but when I include the date of the one of the [G1] or [G2] tables, then it gets removed when I want null values. If I include both in the WHERE function, then I get 0 rows. The result I'd like is:

```
[ID] [Date] [Item] [G1].[Price] [G2].[Price]
3    07/11  Bat    21.00        NULL
4    07/11  Ball   NULL         12.55
5    07/11  Pump   NULL         NULL
```

The code which I have is:

```
SELECT [I].[ID], [I].[DATE], [I].[ITEM], [BT].[PRICE], [BL].[PRICE] 
FROM [ITEMS] [I]
LEFT JOIN [GOODS1] [G1] ON [I].[ITEM] = [G1].[ITEM]
LEFT JOIN [GOODS2] [G2] ON [I].[ITEM] = [G2].[ITEM]
WHERE [I].[DATE] = '2018-11-07'
AND [G1].[DATE] = '2018-11-07'
AND [G2].[DATE] = '2018-11-07'
```

If I don't include the final 2 lines of that code, I get 5 lines, duplicating the ID's of 3, and 4 for the multiple price lines.

Wondered if I could change it to something like:

```
AND ([G1].[DATE] = '2018-11-07 or [G1].[DATE] Not Exists)
```

Much appreciate any help here!

Comment: The way you're using the outer joined columns in the `where` clause effectively changes the `left outer join`s to `inner join`s. You can either move the conditions to the `on` clauses as suggested by Sanal Sunny or, in a less elegant solution, allow for nulls explicitly in the `where` clause, e.g. `... and ( [G1].[DATE] = '2018-11-07' or [G1].[DATE] is NULL ) and ...` or `... and Coalesce( [G1].[DATE], '2018-11-07' ) = '2018-11-07' and ...`. Once you understand how it works the `on` clause solution is clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below query

```
 SELECT [I].[ID], [I].[DATE], [I].[ITEM], [G1].[PRICE]*[Qty] AS G1Price
       ,[G2].[PRICE]*[Qty] AS G2Price 
 FROM [ITEMS] [I]
 LEFT JOIN [GOODS1] [G1] ON [I].[ITEM] = [G1].[ITEM] AND [I].[DATE]=[G1].[DATE]
 LEFT JOIN [GOODS2] [G2] ON [I].[ITEM] = [G2].[ITEM] AND [I].[DATE]=[G2].[DATE]
 WHERE I.[DATE]= '2018-11-07'
```

Comment: THANKS!
That works perfectly. I didn't know about the JOIN ON... **AND** capabilities, so thank you very much!!